# UPDATE is updating some fields but not others

Tags: php, mysqli

Ok, this is an odd one for some reason.  UPDATE is updating fields, but it completely bypasses this one field, and I can't seem to find a reason why.

The field is **partdesc**

Here is the entire code:

```
<?php
require_once('connectvars.php');
echo '<div id="postwrap">'
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>PDI NCMR - Edit</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/postie.css" />
</head>
<body>
   <div id="logo">
    <img src="../images/PDI_Logo_2.1.gif" alt="PDI Logo" />
</div>

<?php

function cleanPostVar(&$dbc, $key) {
   if (array_key_exists($key, $_POST)) {
     return mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST[$key]));
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}

// Connect to the database
    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

      $id= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim(0));
      if(isset($_GET['id']))
         $id= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_GET["id"]));

      if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $id= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST["id"]));

// Enter data into the database
    $ab = cleanPostVar($dbc,'ab');
    $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim(date('Y-m-d',strtotime ($_POST['date']))));
    $part = cleanPostVar($dbc,'part');
    $rev = cleanPostVar($dbc,'rev');
    $partdesc = cleanPostVar($dbc,'partdesc');
    $ncmrqty = cleanPostVar($dbc,'ncmrqty');
    $comp = cleanPostVar($dbc,'comp');
    $ncmrid = cleanPostVar($dbc,'ncmrid');
    $rma = cleanPostVar($dbc,'rma');
    $jno = cleanPostVar($dbc,'jno');
    $fdt = cleanPostVar($dbc,'fdt');
    $cof = cleanPostVar($dbc,'cof');
    $fab1= cleanPostVar($dbc,'fab1');
    $fab2= cleanPostVar($dbc,'fab2');
    $fab3= cleanPostVar($dbc,'fab3');
    $non= cleanPostVar($dbc,'non');
    $dis= cleanPostVar($dbc,'dis');
    $comm= cleanPostVar($dbc,'comm');
    $caad= cleanPostVar($dbc,'caad');
    $po= cleanPostVar($dbc,'po');
    $pod = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['pod']))));
    $dri = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['dri']))));

    $query = "UPDATE testbed SET ab = '$ab', date = '$date', part = '$part', rev = '$rev' , partdesc = '$partdesc' , ncmrqty = '$ncmrqty' , comp = '$comp' , ncmrid = '$ncmrid' , rma = '$rma' , jno = '$jno' , fdt = '$fdt' , cof = '$cof' , fab1 = '$fab1' , fab2 = '$fab2' , fab3 = '$fab3' , non = '$non' , dis = '$dis' , comm = '$comm' , caad = '$caad' , po = '$po' , pod = '$pod' , dri = '$dri'  WHERE id = '$id'";

// echo your raw query and look for obvious errors
     echo "Query is : " . $query . "<br />";

// and at least use a basic mechanism to trap possibles errors
       mysqli_query($dbc, $query)  or die('Query Error : ' . mysqli_error($dbc));


// Confirm success with the user
        echo '<p>If you wish to edit more NCMRs, please <a href="list.php">go to the admin page!</a></p>';

// Clear the form data
    $id = "";
    $ab = "";
    $date = "";
    $part = "";
    $rev = "";
    $partdesc = "";
    $ncmrqty = "";
    $comp = "";
    $ncmrid = "";
    $rma = "";
    $jno = "";
    $fdt = "";
    $cof = "";
    $fab1= "";
    $fab2= "";
    $fab3= "";
    $non= "";
    $dis= "";
    $comm= "";
    $caad= "";
    $po= "";
    $pod = "";
    $dri = "";
            mysqli_close($dbc);
            }

  else {    

// Grab the profile data from the database
if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM testbed WHERE id = '$id'";
  }
  else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM testbed WHERE id = '$id'";
  }

    $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

  if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1) { 
// The user row was found so display the user data
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
echo "<form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>";
    echo '<fieldset>';

        echo '<div id="box1">';
            if (empty($row['ab'])) $row['ab'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['date'])) $row['date'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['part'])) $row['part'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['rev'])) $row['rev'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['partdesc'])) $row['partdesc'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['ncmrqty'])) $row['ncmrqty'] = "Empty";
            echo '<div id="ab"><span class="b">Added By:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="ab" value="' . $row['ab'] . '" /></div>';
            echo '<div id="date"><span class="b">Date Filed:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="date" value="' . $row['date'] . '" /></div>';
            echo '<div id="part"><span class="b">Part Number:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="part" value="' . $row['part'] . '" /></div>';
            echo '<div id="rev"><span class="b">Part Revision:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="rev" value="' . $row['rev'] . '" /></div>';
            echo '<div id="partdesc"><span class="b">Part Description:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea rows="4" cols="22">' . $row['partdesc'] . '</textarea></div>';
            echo '<div id="ncmrqty"><span class="b">NCMR Qty:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="ncmrqty" value="' . $row['ncmrqty'] . '" /></div>';
        echo '</div>';

//Company, Customer NCMR, Internal RMA, and Job Number
        echo '<div id="box2">';
            if (empty($row['comp'])) $row['comp'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['ncmrid'])) $row['ncmrid'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['rma'])) $row['rma'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['jno'])) $row['jno'] = "Empty";
                echo '<div id="comp"><span class="b">Company:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="comp" value="' . $row['comp'] . '" /></div>';
                    echo '<div id="ncmrid"><span class="b">Customer NCMR ID:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="ncmrid" value="' . $row['ncmrid'] . '" /></div>';
                    echo '<div id="rma"><span class="b">Internal RMA #:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="rma" value="' . $row['rma'] . '" /></div>';
                    echo '<div id="jno"><span class="b">Job #:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="jno" value="' . $row['jno'] . '" /></div>';
        echo '</div>';

//Type of Failure and Class of Failure
        echo '<div id="box3">';
            echo '<h2>Failure</h2>';
                echo '<div id="cof"><span class="b">Class of Failure:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="cof"  size="15" value="' . $row['cof'] . '" /></div>';
                echo '<div id="fdt"><span class="b">Failure Due To:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="fdt"  size="15" value="' . $row['fdt'] . '" /></div>';

            echo '</div>';

//Fabricators
        echo '<div id="box4">';
            echo '<h2>Fabricators</h2>';
if ($row['fab1']=="--None--")
{
    echo'<div id="fab1">';
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
    $mysqli->select_db('user');
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user"); 
    echo "<SELECT name='fab1'>\n";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<option value='{$row['user']}'>{$row['user']}</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n";
    echo '</div>';
}
else
{
    echo'<div id="fab1">';
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
    $mysqli->select_db('user');
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user"); 
    echo "<SELECT name='fab1'>\n";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<option value='{$row['user']}'>{$row['user']}</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n";
    echo '</div>';
}


if ($row['fab2']="--None--")
{
    echo'<div id="fab2">';
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
    $mysqli->select_db('user');
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user"); 
    echo "<SELECT name='fab2'>\n";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<option value='{$row['user']}'>{$row['user']}</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n";
    echo '</div>';
}
else
{
    echo '<div id="fab2"><span class="b"></span><input type="text" name="fab1"  size="20" value="' . $row['fab1'] . '" /></div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
if ($row['fab3']="--None--")
{
    echo'<div id="fab3">';
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
    $mysqli->select_db('user');
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user"); 
    echo "<SELECT name='fab3'>\n";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<option value='{$row['user']}'>{$row['user']}</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n";
    echo '</div>';
}
else
{
    echo '<div id="fab3"><span class="b"></span><input type="text" name="fab1"  size="20" value="' . $row['fab1'] . '" /></div>';
    echo '</div>';
}       echo '</div>';

//Nonconformity, Disposition, Comments and Comments & Additional Details
        echo '<div id="box5">';
            if (empty($row['non'])) $row['non'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['dis'])) $row['dis'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['comm'])) $row['comm'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['caad'])) $row['caad'] = "Empty";

            echo '<div id="non"><span class="b">Nonconformity:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea rows="4" cols="105">' . $row['non'] . '</textarea></div>';
            echo '<div id="dis"><span class="b">Disposition:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea rows="4" cols="105">' . $row['dis'] . '</textarea></div>';
            echo '<div id="comm"><span class="b">Comments:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea rows="4" cols="105">' . $row['comm'] . '</textarea></div>';
            echo '<div id="caad"><span class="b">Comments and/or Additional Details:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea rows="4" cols="105">' . $row['caad'] . '</textarea></div>';

                echo '<div id="podr">';
                        if (empty($row['po'])) $row['po'] ="Empty";
                        if (empty($row['pod'])) $row['pod'] ="Empty";
                        if (empty($row['dir'])) $row['dri'] ="Empty";

                    echo '<div id="po"><span class="b">PO:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="po"  size="7" value="' . $row['po'] . '" /></div>';
                    echo '<div id="pod"><span class="b">PO Date:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="pod"  size="7" value="' . $row['pod'] . '" /></div>';
                    echo '<div id="dri"><span class="b">Date Received:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="dri"  size="7" value="' . $row['dri'] . '" /></div>';
                echo '</div>';
            echo '<div id="button2"><input type="submit" value="Submit Edits" name="submit" /></div>';
//Save ID so it can be used with POST request.
echo "<input type='hidden' value='$id' name='id'/>"; 

        echo '</div>';
    echo '</fieldset>';
echo '</form>';
        }
    }

echo '</div>';

?>
</body>
</html>
```

As far as I can tell these parts are dealing with the code in question.

The part to sanitize the script:

```
   $partdesc = cleanPostVar($dbc,'partdesc');
```

The part to update the script.

```
$query = "UPDATE ncmr SET ab = '$ab', date = '$date', part = '$part', rev = '$rev' , partdesc = '$partdesc' , ncmrqty = '$ncmrqty' , comp = '$comp' , ncmrid = '$ncmrid' , rma = '$rma' , jno = '$jno' , fdt = '$fdt' , cof = '$cof' , fab1 = '$fab1' , fab2 = '$fab2' , fab3 = '$fab3' , non = '$non' , dis = '$dis' , comm = '$comm' , caad = '$caad' , po = '$po' , pod = '$pod' , dri = '$dri'  WHERE id = '$id'";
```

The part to show the description of said field, if none is there enter Empty into the field till otherwise entered by person.

```
if (empty($row['partdesc'])) $row['partdesc'] = "Empty";

            echo '<div id="partdesc"><span class="b">Part Description:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea rows="4" cols="22">' . $row['partdesc'] . '</textarea></div>';
```

And that's it.  Each one has one form or another mind you correctly as **partdesc**. Now also mind you this is also being edited in Notepad ++ and is encoded in UTF +8 without BOM, so there are no descrepencies as far as I can tell with the code in question.

Is there something I am missing or is this just something because all the other code is posting, and it looks identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your textarea has no `name` attribute. Since the key in `$_POST` is based on the name, this means that text is not stored where you think it is.

A good way to debug a problem like this is to print out the value of `$_POST` at the start of the php file so that you can make sure it actually contains the data you expect. If you think a particular SQL query is failing, a good debugging strategy is to print out the query so that you can try making it by hand and see if SQL objects.

Comment: I have a printout of the area in question, hence why I am able to ask the question, because I know it's not posting correctly. What do you mean it has no name attribute?

Comment: you textarea filed dont have a name attribute associated with it. please check your code and provide a name to the textarea field 'partdesc'.

Comment: @Russell Zahniser Nevermind figured it out, thanks for the direction... it's appreciated!